# How to use $_POST

Tags: php

I have the following PHP file:

```
<?php
    echo <<<_END
    <form method='POST' action='index.php' enctpye='multipart/form-data'>
    New Content: <input type='text' name='content'/><br/>
    New Image: <input type="file" name='image' size='10' /><br/>
    Products:
        <select name="filename">
        <option value="product1.txt">Product 1</option>
        <option value="product2.txt">Product 2</option>
        <option value="product3.txt">Product 3</option>
        </select>
    </form> 
    _END;
    echo <<<_END
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
    _END;

    echo $_POST["filename"];
?>
```

I am getting this error when i try to run this.

```
Notice: Undefined index: filename in `C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php` on line 18
```

Sorry, I am new to PHP but should this not echo either product1.txt, product2.txt or product3.txt?

Comment: As long as you are submitting the form, yes.

Comment: which framework you are using ? It seems you are using some framework.When form will be submited then only you will get required output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get post values only after submitting form,

```
if(isset($_POST["filename"])){
    echo $_POST["filename"];
}
```

Or better give name `submit` or something to your submit button & check,

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    echo isset($_POST["filename"]) ? $_POST["filename"] : '';
    echo isset($_POST["content"]) ? $_POST["content"] : '';
    .....
}
```

**Helpful:** [*What does this error mean in PHP?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php?lq=1)

Comment: You should check the other vars, because users can manipulate your form.

Comment: even shorter: `if(isset($_POST['submit'], $_POST['filename'], $_POST['content'])) { ...`

Comment: @Recode - We have to keep some work for user to do himself & learn :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if it's set:

```
if(isset($_POST['filename']))
 echo $_POST['filename'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to try first if the variable is set http://php.net/manual/fr/function.isset.php